# Event when resizing QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, events, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have a QGraphicsScene and a QGraphicsView allocated to it (c++).
I would like to get an event each time the QGraphicsScene is resized in order to  draw an adapted pixmap size.

However I couldn't find a resize event for the QGraphicsScene (just for the QGraphicsView), and I couldn't find a pixmap capability in the QGraphicsView (just for the QGraphicsScene).

How should I proceed ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QGraphicsScene` is an abstract that represents an infinite plane with graphics elements on it. `QGraphicsView` is a "window" that allows you to look at particular part of the scene. Thus, your question kinda does not make sense, because you cannot "resize" an infinite plane. Instead you should operate in terms of the view.